# Magento1.8.1.0 - Admin session timeout won't go above 15min

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, session, timeout

I have an issue with the Admin session timeout in Magento shop older version `1.8.1.0`.

I have configured the value in seconds -> `3600` in Admin configuration but it still closes Admin session in `900` seconds.

I have checked the database and there is only

```
admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime 86200
```

There is no `admin/security/session_lifetime` as I have seen in some responses to this topic.

Could it be something in the PHP config? If it is, where could I find those variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this value in admin :
**System** ->  **Configuration** ->  **ADVANCED** -> **Admin**.
Under Security, in the **Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)**

https://cl.ly/68f36e8f3db0

If you have it **900** , update it to **86200**

Flush the magento cache.

If that doesnt fix try to increase your cookielifetime :
**System** -> **Configuration** -> **GENERAL** -> **Web** -> **Session Cookie Management**

```
Cookie Lifetime 86400
Cookie Path /
Cookie Domain .enteryourwebsitenamehere.com
Use HTTP Only No
Cookie Restriction Mode No
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked even without clearing the cache.

Comment: Glad it helped @frakesTheArtisan